# Why I can't see Launch(Splash) Screen when change Root View in swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, splash-screen, launch

the problem I have is to remove the root arrow on the story board and set up the root view in the **AppDelegate** file to dynamically change the RootView.

There is no problem moving the root view, but the existing `splashScreen(Launch Screen)` is not visible. Why can't you see it? How can I see the `splashScreen(Launch Screen)` and go to the root view?

**Main.Storyboard**

[image: Main]

**Login.Storyboard,**

[image]

**Launch.Storyboard**

[image]

**Move Root Screen in  AppDelegate.swift**

```swift
var window: UIWindow?

    func switchStartUI() {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartViewController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
    }

    func switchToMainUI() {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
    }

    func switchLoginUI(_ pushtype : String) {
        let loginStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = loginStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainLoginController") as! MainLoginController
        viewController.pushType = pushtype
        self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
      if let screenData : String = LocalStorage.get("ScreenView") as? String {
            switch (screenData) {
            case "success":
                switchToMainUI()
            case "success1":
                switchLoginUI("")
            case "success2":
                switchLoginUI("")
            default:
                switchStartUI()
            }
        } else {
            switchStartUI()
        }

        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

I want to see the splash screen and move on to the root view

There is already an image on my splash screen. It worked normally. But I can't see the splash screen after dynamically modifying the root view. I'm the same

### I can only see the black screen. when remove two function

```swift
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

To me, the white screen appears and then I go to the root view page.

I don't know why I can't see the splash screen.

How can I solve this problem??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple solution. 'Launch.Added root arrow to 'Storyboard'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It also happened to me. However, I select from simulator **Hardware -> Erase all content and settings** or **restarting device** will fix your problem.